# Spring Boot test configuration for service which extends a component

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am trying to set up some testing for my service layers in Spring Boot.

This works great for a normal service:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ThreadSystemServiceImplTest {
    /**
     * This configures this test so that the correct implementation is tested
     */
    @TestConfiguration
    static class ThreadSystemServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ThreadSystemService testService() {
            return new ThreadSystemServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private ThreadSystemService service;

    @MockBean
    private ThreadSystemRepository repository;

    ...
}
```

However, I now have a service set up like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DrawingServiceImpl extends DrawingFunctions implements DrawingService {
    ....
}
```

DrawingFunctions has:

```
@Component
public class DrawingFunctions extends ToDoFunctions {
    /**
     * Logging Manager
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER=LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private CommodityPartPORepository cppoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WorkOrderService woService;

    @Autowired
    private InventorySearch inventorySearch;

    ...
}
```

When I try to run a test, then I get errors about no qualifying beans from the extended classes, such as `WorkOrderService` and `InventorySearch`.  One of the extended classes also has

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

which seems to create more issues.

I can set up beans in my test configuration much like the bean for `ThreadSystemService` in the working example.  However, this would be quite an extensive list, almost all of which I will not need to reference for these tests.  Is there any way to not include the extended classes for a specific test, or is there an easy way to set up this kind of test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DataJpaTest instead of @PersistenceContext in order to use a test EntityManager

[Documentation DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

Comment: `@PersistenceContext` is in one of the extended classes, not in the test class.  As I understand it, I can use `@DataJpaTest` as an annotation for `ThreadSystemServiceImplTest`, but I'm still getting the same issues with no qualifying beans for the other service classes.